# Which software can create real mechanical simulation?

Tags: 3d, simulation, catia

I know this SE is not the best place to ask this question but there are no mechanical eng. or CAD related SE.

I want to make simulations which transmits movement with contacts. For example rotation of series of gears with rotating only first gear. I searched a solution for Catia but only solution that I found was using constrains which is not suitable for my purpose.

Does anyone know a software that can make this?

Comment: Actually, [engineering.se] is a thing. Your question **may** also be on-topic on [softwarerecs.se]. Either way, please read the site’s guidelines before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be asking mechanical engineering questions on [engineering.se](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/). Engineering.SE wont accept external resource questions so in this case you should ask [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Depends on how accurate your simulation has to be, what you need to simulate and what the audience of your results are. If you really need real engineering accuracy then your main options are:

- MSC Adams
- Simpack
- LMS Virtual.Lab

If you dont really need full on contact but mathematical modeling might do then consider:

- Matlab/simulink
- Modellica (Open modellica, dymola, wolfram modeller)
- SimX

Which are the top contenders. Many of the CAD aps can do rudimentary contact simulation but its not terribly accurate in terms of analysis, more at par with animation engines, good for visualization only. I remember doing this in Catia with contacs years back... But then that would contend with simpack.

Answer (score 0):

I think now days you have a lot of options on 3D software that accept phisics. For example you can try Blender.

Here is a video doing that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j1WNbpX7HPo

Comment: Well yes and no, it kind of works but wouldn't give you the right answer as the simulator in blender is toy it doesnt really allow for very a accurate simulation engineering wise.